# Why HTML is getting displayed as String

Tags: html, grails

I have a result as List

```
[[<a onclick="viewEmpDetails('563291f0af6a1ecb740f904c','false','UniqueId')" title='View' style='cursor:pointer'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey' style='width:30px;'> </i></a>, 02/02/49, 02/02/49, 02/02/1949, 11-Jan-1916, 10-Feb-33]]
```

And I am using below code to iterate

```
<g:each in="${session.treeGridJsonObject}"  var="lists">
  <g:each in="${lists}"  var="list">
  <td>${list}</td>
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

But I am getting html code as string in GSP.[image]

How I am adding html data in controller

```
htmlData += "<a onclick=\"viewEmpDetails('"+row['UniqueId']+"','false','UniqueId')\" title='View' style='cursor:pointer'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey' style='width:30px;'> </i></a>"
```

When I try to debug it showing double " " quotation.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is to prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). This way, if a user submits some javascript, it will not run when displayed to other people. There are multiple ways to output raw data:

```
${raw(content)}
```

or

```
${content.encodeAsRaw()}
```

or

```
<g:encodeAs codec="Raw">${content}</g:encodeAs>
```

or

```
<g:encodeAs codec="None">${content}</g:encodeAs>
```

See http://mrhaki.blogspot.nl/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html